# Android Animation Hide And Show View

Tags: android

I am learning about animations, can't find a good document on the net anyway I would like to do the following:

1. Click button to hide view - works OK
2. Click same button again to show view - Not OK

The problem with this is that the view only shows up about 10% at the bottom of the screen and the rest of the view is 90% of blank / white space. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Code below:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                          @Override
                          public void run() {


                                if(bottomButtonLayout.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
                                {
                                    //Shown - Hide It
                                    bottomButtonLayout.animate().translationY(bottomButtonLayout.getHeight()).alpha(0.0f).setDuration(900).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter()


                                    {
                                           @Override
                                           public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                                           super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                                           bottomButtonLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                      }
                                           });

                                    iconHideView = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.icnHideView);
                                    iconHideView.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_up);

                                }
                                else if(bottomButtonLayout.getVisibility()==View.GONE)
                                {
                                    //Hidden - Show it
                                    bottomButtonLayout.setAlpha(1);
                                    bottomButtonLayout.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(500).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter()


                                    {
                                           @Override
                                           public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                                           super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                                           bottomButtonLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                   }
                                          });

                                    iconHideView = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.icnHideView);
                                    iconHideView.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_down);


                                }  


                          }

                      });
```

Comment: You are animating something that does not exist. You should set the view to VISIBLE, wait for it to calculate its layout and dimensions, and just before onDraw() animate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the logic i implemented with your idea. It may help you.

XML Code :

```
<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width = "match_parent"
   android:layout_height = "match_parent"
   android:background = "#ffffff"
   android:gravity = "center"
   android:orientation = "vertical">

  <TextView
     android:id = "@+id/tv"
     android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
     android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity = "center"
     android:gravity = "center"
     android:text = "MOVING TEXT"
     android:textSize = "24sp"/>

  <Button
     android:id = "@+id/but"
     android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
     android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
     android:text = "click me"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then, in your java code, write these snippets.

Java :

```
boolean flag;
final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
Button but = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but);
```

Then on button click listener implement the animation logic.

```
but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {

    if (!flag) {
      tv.animate().translationY(tv.getHeight()).alpha(0.0f).setDuration(1200).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
          tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          flag = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        }
      });
    } else {
// Part you require
      tv.animate().translationY(0).alpha(1.0f).setDuration(1200).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
          tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {

          flag = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        }
      });

    }

  }
});
```

Queries ..? Let me know.

Comment: Thanks, the code works with the following 2 changes:

1. boolean flag; changed to boolean fl;
2. tv.animate().translationY(tv.getHeight() - 100) changed to tv.animate().translationY(0).

Add these modifications to your answer and I will accept. Thanks again.

(In my case I used LinearLayout with buttons instead of textView)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Changes you mentioned was done. Thanks again for notifying it.